# Push just one file to GitHub from a local repository

Tags: git, version-control, github, repository

I have a repo with multiple scripts. One of them is especially useful and I want to share it using GitHub.

How can I export one file (with commit history) to a GitHub repo without sharing all other scripts from the same repo?

Something like:

```
git remote add 'origin' git@github.com:user/Project.git
git push -u 'origin' ./useful-script.sh
```

But how do I specify a single filename? Or should I create some kind of special 'partial' commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to use `filter-branch` to rewrite your history and strip everything but that single file:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter '
  git rm --cached -f -r .;
  git add ./useful-script.sh;
' --all
```

should do the job.

If `--index-filter` does not work (I'm not sure about that `git add` there), try `--tree-filter' with the same argument.

Comment: `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached -fr . ; git add ./useful-script.sh' -- --all` . I guess the file's removed by `rm` and this gives an error: "fatal: pathspec 'amarocker' did not match any files".

Comment: Tried with xargs: `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git ls-tree -r --name-only master | fgrep -v useful-script.sh | xargs git rm --cached -fr' -- --all`. Unfortunately, this leaves commits related to other files intact :(

Comment: Same result. Thanks, at least this gives some hope :)